# infinite scroll in reactJS, display data oncw I scroll

Tags: reactjs, scroll, infinite

is it possible to repeat the post once I scrolled the page?...
i had two post data in my newsfeed and I want it to be infinite as I scroll.

I want to display the data after I scroll

Answer (score 0):

For achieving infinite scroll you can use a package called react-infinite-scroll-component [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component), This allows you to load the data multiple times when scrolled and shows a loading animation also with is.
Hope this solves your issue.
If you want detailed elaboration about it, you can check out this video regarding infinite scrolling on youtube
[Code with Harry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLox5lhwaEU)

Comment: it is posssible to display repeatedly the data once all data had been displayed already?

Comment: I would suggest you keep track of the items displayed, once it reaches your data length you reset the count tracker and start from zero again and display the data repeatedly.

Comment: I mean two arrays in data? i want to display it repeatedly, so it makes my newsfeed page infinite once I scroll it.

Comment: I mean if you reset the counter to zero once all data is displayed, it will make an infinite scroll.